# Windows 8: Failed to change remote desktop (RDP) default port number

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I followed the link here  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759 to change the remote desktop default port number in my Win8 Pro (x64) but it failed.

I have already set the firewall to allow the new port number and reboot the computer.

I can't use the new port number to connect but the port 3389 is still working.  Seems the solution is not working for Win 8.

I've tried it in Win7 Pro (x86) and it works perfectly.

Did I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: I use this method on Server 2003 and 2008.  So I *know* it works on them, I havent tried it on 8 though.  Did you double check that the registry change took?

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem, I'd forgotten the firewall. Simple, but missed.
Just resolved this on Win8 Pro x64